# Prepared statements and class inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, pdo, statements

I have a problem when doing a prepared statement in PHP. My main goal is to create two classes, the first one for connecting (Conexion) to the server and the database and the second one to do prepared statements (RealizarConsultas).

I have decided that the class used to do statements should inherit from "Conexion". By doing this I pretend to connect with the database each time I use the function "RealizarConsultas::MostrarConsulta()". This function should connect with the database, then it should do the prepared statement and finally it should close the connection.

Class used for connection.

```
<?php

    class Conexion extends PDO{

        protected $conexionDb;

        public function Conexion(){ 
            try{
                $conexionDb=new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=euroburo','root','');
                $conexionDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $conexionDb->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");



            }catch(Exception $e){

                echo "Error: ".$e->getLine();

            }
        }
        public function stopConexion(){
            $conexionDb->close();
        }

    }
?>
```

Class used to do prepare statements.

```
<?php
    require("conexion.php");
    class RealizarConsulta extends Conexion{
        public function RealizarConsulta(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function MostrarConsulta($consulta){
            $resultado=$this->conexionDb->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute();
            $final = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
            print_r($final);
            $this->stopConexion();
        }
    }

?>
```

My main problem is in this line, located inside "RealizarConsulta::MostrarConsulta()".

```
$resultado=$this->conexionDb->prepare($consulta);
```

Each time I call to the function (RealizarConsulta::MostrarConsulta());

This error appears: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.

I understand that this error tells me that $this->conexionDb is not an object but I don't really understand why. The reason I don't understand the error is due to the fact that $conexionDb is a protected variable created in the parent class, as a protected variable "RealizarConsulta" class should inherit it without any problem and I should have access to it. $conexionDb as you can see is initialised when the constuctor is called, and it should hold the information related to the connection.

As you can see through my reasoning, $conexionDb should be a reference to an object that belongs to "Conexion" class and I should have access to it in "RealizarConsulta" class.

I would like to know in what I am failing and how can I resolve the error. Thanks

Comment: Why are you wrapping PDO to begin with?

Comment: *"the class used to do statements should inherit from "Conexion""* -- this is a bad design decision. It should not extend `Conexion`; it should get a `Conexion` as argument in the constructor. Think a little about it: you may want to create and run multiple prepared statements during the script execution; there is not needed to create a separate connection for each statement. It's a waste of resources and there are situations when this approach prevents you accomplishing your goal (you cannot wrap two statements in a transaction f.e.).

Comment: `$conexionDb` and `$this->conexionDb` are entirely different variables. Also, naming a constructor after the class name is PHP/4 syntax—they already trigger a warning in PHP/7 and will possibly get removed some day.

Comment: PeeHaa - I don't understand the "wrapping" expression (I am not from an Anglo-Saxon country),

Comment: Axiac - I think that your approach is much more logical than mine, in fact after thinking about considering a statement as a connection I have realised that is not a clever decision, they are and should be completely different things.Álvaro Gonzalez - Is nice to know that. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your class level variable, but unless you're leaving out some code, you're not assigning your local variable to the class level. In PHP, you do have to do that. For example

```
class A {
    protected $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = 'Hello';
    }

    public function echo() {
        $a = 'World';
        echo $this->a . ' ' . $a;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->echo()
```

Would echo `Hello World`. This is because in `echo()`, `$a` is a local variable, and `$this->a` is a variable scoped to the class. They're two different variables that hold two different values.

So your constructor should look like this

```
    public function __construct() { 
        try {
            $conexionDb= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=euroburo', 'root', '');
            $conexionDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conexionDb->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            $this->conexionDb = $conexionDb;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: ".$e->getLine();
        }
    }
```

Also, as a side note, it's highly recommended to use `public function __construct()` as your constructor in PHP, not a function with the same name as the class